# Find the Nth row that matches a condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pattern-matching

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(my_list).reshape(3,3), columns = list("abc"))
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  4  8  9
3  0  1  0
```

How can I delete just the nth instance of a row matching a condition (for example the second instance of `df['a'] == 4`)?

In this case the result should be:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
3  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the index of the nth `True` value of the expression `(df['a'] == 4)`.

```
nth = 2
df.drop(df.index[(df['a'] == 4)][nth-1])

   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
3  0  1  0
```

Where,

```
df['a'] == 4

0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

And,

```
df.index[(df['a'] == 4)]
# Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64')
```